# Keyboard shortcut for Visual Studio code editor Members and Types combos

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I wonder what is the keyboard shortcut for these two combo boxs and specially the right part which list all the members of current class and is very handy for navigating a large class.

I tried to figure it out myself but I do not know the exact names to search for it.

[image: Screenshot showing Visual Studio 2010, in a code file with the Members and Types combos highlighted]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That whole thing is called "Navigation bar" (Window.MovetoNavigationBar) and can be activated by default by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. There doesn't seem to be a shortcut for the right side of the navigation bar, so pressing the short cut key always takes you to the combo box on the left side. You can use Tab to jump between the combo boxes.

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> which takes you to the left-hand combo. If you hover over each one in turn (at least in VS2k8) it shows you a tooltip which identifies the two combos as "Types" and "Members", respectively.

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will take you to the right-hand combo and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> will expand the combo for you.

Comment: in VS2010 there is no hover tool-tip  for them

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative Resharper approach #1

[**"Go to file member"**](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_File_Member.html)  which is **"Alt+\"** .

go to link for advanced features

### Alternative Resharper approach #2

**"[Go to Next/Previous Member](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Next_Previous_Member.html)"** with **Alt+Down or Alt+Up**

this one is very handy and my favorite :